# Identify high current LED Package name

Tags: led, identification, packages

Based on another question recently asked, this package is very common, used in high current LED applications (0.5W ~ 3W). The package includes the led chip, lens, heatsinking, but can vary in light radiation patterns. Very common, they have been around for years if not decade. But I have never found a common package name, unlike other led types (5mm, 3mm, Straw Hat, 1206, 0805, etc). Is there a common name, or even a JEDEC or similar standard to standardize this type of package?

[image: Front view]
[image: Back view]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package is called by different trade names by companies,

Lumileds Corp calls them **"Barracuda"**,
while
Osram Opto. calls them **"Dragon"**.

[image: led-package-barracuda-lumileds]

The **important feature** of the package is a heat-conducting metal center, the **"heatsink slug"**, that can be soldered onto a larger heatsink below:

[image]

For details and source, see the chapter on LED packaging of the somewhat-retired LED-related website [Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/) - (note different domain).

See the bottom-left image: [Chapter 11: Packaging - Fig 11.5.](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~schubert/Light-Emitting-Diodes-dot-org/chap11/chap11.htm)

A possible reason for not having a clear type code for this package could be that it was not actually a LED package, but just a more generic heatsink-with-extra-plastic-lens.

---

*<sub>Barracuda was, at least initially, actually referring to the type of LED die itself, not the package. See [ledmuseum.candlepower.us](http://ledmuseum.candlepower.us/agilent.htm) and  [Philips LED Update - page 8](http://public.ises.org/PREA/2_Presentations/3_Tech_Strat_Edu/9_Philips_LED.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Nice find. It also goes with the name convention for piranha led packages (Figure B & C in link).

Comment: Where did that term "heatsink plug" come from? is it "slug"?

Comment: @Passerby But then, the "heatsink slug" is just that piece of metal, drawn in pink. (slug means something like blob).

Comment: Figure 11.5 refers to label d as heatsink plug, and then explains that Barricuda is the trade name for that package by Lumileds. Same as the Piranha being refered to simply as b, low profile.

Comment: Oops, put plug instead of slug. fixed.

Comment: Ok... but "heatsink slug" means something like "blob of metal shaped heat conductor" I think. The image description does not care about the package shapes, just the thermal-relevant aspects. In the second image, text to the right, I think it's about soldering that pink part, not the whole package.

Comment: And I think from the image description on 11.5 that "Dragon" is the "Barracuda"-like package soldered to that star-shaped heatsink.

Comment: It notes that Barracude and Dragon refer to both label d and e, with d being the led, and e being the same led on a star shaped pcb.

Comment: Yes, but it's not on the star - the star is part of the package in that case; I think you by these on a tape or so including the star. Could be a good reason for that, like the slug is welded on some part of the star - not sure it's PCB - it's a heatsink, mainly.

Comment: @Passerby Oh, now I got it! Indeed Barracuda and Dragon each is refering to star- and star-less packages, from two companies.

Answer (score 2):

They are usually referred to as "2-SMD, Gull Wing". I haven't seen a standard refer to this type of package.

"Gull wing" actually refers to the shape of the leads. It is a general term that applies to almost all smt packages that have leads bent towards the outside of the pack, such as [QFP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_Flat_Package).

Comment: Gull wing referring to the lead shape though, as opposed to jlead or right-angle.

Comment: @Passerby: yeah. It is a very generic name that doesn't really mean anything. But that is what all of them are using to describe it. Unless it's a star shaped module so they say "star shape"...